Only Select A Specific Fingerprint
I'm trying to use the Plugin.Fingerprint in my .NET MAUI App.
And right now, it's accepting all the fingerprints enrolled in my emulator.
Is it possible to only get the Fingerprint 1 or just a specific fingerprint that is registered on their device?
Tried to research about this and haven't found anything.

AFAIK you cannot do this

That is not possible. The APIs on each platform basically only allow you to verify the biometrics, is this the person we expect yes or no?
Because fingerprints and faces are very privacy sensitive you will not get access to any of the data, that is securely stored in the operating system.
